# How to make urls form one app seen by the other?

Tags: python, django

I did the following:

1. Created an app `usergui`
2. Included it in settings:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #default
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #local
    'ticketsdb.apps.TicketsdbConfig',
    'usergui.apps.UserguiConfig'
]
```

3. Created `urls.py inside` usergui`

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.auth.as_view(), name="auth")
]
```

4. Modified urls.py in the main folder as following:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(usergui.urls)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)

]
```

And I am getting an error:

```py
File "/home/me/Desktop/ticketing/ticketing/ticketing/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    path('', include(usergui.urls)),
NameError: name 'usergui' is not defined
```

Why does it not recognize the app?

Answer (score 0):

Add app_name to the usergui urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'usergui'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.auth.as_view(), name="auth")
]
```